# About the expected value of a sum of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value

In the textbook I'm reading, it states
$$E[g(X,Y)+h(X,Y)]=E[g(X,Y)]+E[h(X,Y)]$$
as a theorem, and derives
$$E[X+Y]=E[X]+E[Y]$$
as a corollary by putting $g(X,Y)=X$ and $h(X,Y)=Y$.
But isn't the opposite more natural? That is, if
$$E[X+Y]=E[X]+E[Y]$$
holds for any random variables $X$ and $Y$, then since $g(X,Y)$ and $h(X,Y)$ are themselves random variables,
$$E[g(X,Y)+h(X,Y)]=E[g(X,Y)]+E[h(X,Y)]$$
holds. Am not understanding something?

Comment: If I need to see that you're not understanding something, I need to see which textbook this is, which chapter you are reading from. At the moment, I know just about as much as you do, so I'm confused as well.

Comment: That being said, both deductions seem valid.

Comment: My guess would be that your book is trying to prove this using only the minimal amount of measure theoretic set-up, i.e. you want to work this out using the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$ as the only measure in question. In that context, it is probably most natural to do what your textbook does.